# Reading from CSV file without tokenizing words into letters and numbers into digits

Tags: python-3.x, csv, urllib

I am downloading csv file and then reading it using csv module. For some reason, words and numbers get tokenized into letters and single digits. However, there is exception with "1 Mo", "3 Mo" etc.

I am getting csv file from here:

```
url = https://home.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/daily-treasury-rates.csv/2022/all?type=daily_treasury_yield_curve&field_tdr_date_value=2022&page&_format=csv
```

I use Python 3.10 and the code looks as follows:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import csv

response = urlopen(url)
content = response.read().decode('utf-8')
csv_data = csv.reader(content, delimiter=',')
for row in csv_data:
    print(row)
```

Here is what I am getting:

```
['D']
['a']
['t']
['e']
['','']
['1 Mo']
['','']
['2 Mo']
['','']
['3 Mo']
['','']
.
.
.
['30 Yr']
[]
['1']
['1']
['/']
['0']
['8']
['/']
.
.
.
```

I tried different delimiters but it does not help.

**P.S.** When I simply save csv file to drive and then open it - everything works properly. But I don't want to have this extra step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the documentation for `csv.reader` [at this link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#reader-objects):

> `csv.reader(csvfile, dialect='excel', **fmtparams)`
>
> ...`csvfile` can be any object which supports the iterator protocol and returns a string each time its `__next__()` method is called -- file objects and list objects are both suitable...

Notice that your variable `content` is a string, not a file. In Python, strings may be iterators, but their `__next__()` method does not return the next line. You probably want to convert your long CSV string into a *list of lines*, so that `__next__()` (when it is called internally to the `reader` function) will give the next line instead of the next character. Note that this is why your code mysteriously works when you save the CSV to a file first - an open file iterator returns the next line of input each time `__next__()` is invoked.

To accomplish this, try using the following line in place of line 4:

```
content = response.read().decode('utf-8').split("\n")
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was just reading this documentation - you beat me:)

Comment: @user3151858 Haha, nice! Glad to hear you were almost there ;)

Comment: Adding ```.split('\n')``` solved the problem!